# Cannot compile JSP files since new update of Java Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I updated the version of JDK and JRE on my mac which is running Mountain Lion. Knowing that $JAVA_HOME is not anymore set in Mac, I manually set it up.

Ever since that I am unable to deploy code on Google app engine. I have seen a lot of complaints on similar lines and I have taken the following steps so far.

- Pointing Eclipse to the JDK not JRE
- Setting up $JAVA_HOME appropriately
- Setting up the eclipse.ini file so that it points to the right directory with the new JDK

I am currently getting this in the error log which is not at all descriptive of the cause

------------ Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
    Created staging directory at: '/var/folders/fm/44m8l7zn7x71067wvdj7g75w0000gn/T/appcfg5680117283026395820.tmp'
    Using java7 runtime: false
    Scanning for jsp files.
    Compiling jsp files.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.

... all JSP files about 60 of them

Debugging information may be found in /private/var/folders/fm/44m8l7zn7x71067wvdj7g75w0000gn/T/appengine-deploy2728364652103813474.log

And the final error log :

Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJavaFiles(Application.java:803)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.compileJsps(Application.java:760)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:592)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
~

Has anyone managed to solve the problems they were facing, if so how?

I look forward to some feedback

Thanks 
Rajat

Comment: Define "Cannot compile". WHat are you doing, what does it produce?

Comment: I have added the stacktrace in the edit. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Did you work out the problem? I am having similar problems... different error messages.

Comment: I had run into dependency issues - missing includes. Costed me a week.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of “Unable to update app: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.”

While it was true that there was an error in the JSP as indicated by some other answers,
What helped me was to run `<path-to-appengine-java-sdk>\bin\appcfg.cmd update <war-location>` in a command window,
it provided me with a more detailed output then the plugin did and enabled me to resolve the problem [a redundent import in my case] in a matter of minutes.

If this does not help you can have a look at my question:
["Unable to update app: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files." when trying to deply GAE App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092931/unable-to-update-app-failed-to-compile-the-generated-jsp-java-files-when-try/21108168#21108168)
as it includes quite a detailed list of recomendations I collected around the net and tried before I found this solution/workaround.